# What does "gain" mean?

Tags: dc-comics-deck-building

What exactly is meant by "gain" a card. For example, if I am asked to draw a card from my deck- have I gained the card? Or does gain only apply to cards from the lineup I gain for no cost (Cheetah,  Dark Knight )

Answer (score 3):

To gain a card is to take it from the lineup and move it to your discard pile. From page 9 of the [rulebook](http://szellemlovas.hu/tarsasjatekok/szabalyok/dc_comics.pdf):

> **Gaining Cards**
>
> > When a card tells a player to gain a particular card
> >     or a card of your choice, that card is taken and
> >     immediately placed in that player’s discard pile at no
> >     additional cost, unless otherwise directed by the card.

Answer (score -1):

Additionally, if you get a card from another player that is considered gaining a card as well.

Comment: Welcome to the site! your answer would be greatly improved if you added a bit more information so that it could stand on it's own.